# Distance between Zip + 4 codes?

Tags: google-api, geospatial, google-geocoding-api

Is there a way to calculate the average Distance/Drive time between two zip + 4 codes ?

Example : Distance/ Drive time between 71201-6669 , 71106-7444 ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that both zip codes and 4 codes are areas.

If you added these area (polygon) shapefiles into a desktop GIS (think QGIS) then one could find the centroids of the polygons and find the distance between them.
These shapefiles are available online https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24. This was the top result when I Googled 'usa postcode shapefile'